# kill a python process launched at start up

Tags: python, linux, process, startup

I am running a small websocket server python based. For pratical reason I launched it at startup via a small script in init.d:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
echo "Starting mosaicServer"
# run application you want to start
rm /var/log/process.log
python /var/dir/process.py > /var/log/process.log
;;
 stop)
echo "Stopping process"
# kill application you want to stop
    killall process
    ;;
   *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/process {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The problem is that I need to kill this process for testing, but I cannot seem to be able to see the process pid with `ps -all` or `/etc/init.d/process stop`.

If you could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for the process with

```
ps aux | grep -e "[p]rocess"
```

The `[p]` is to ignore the grep process itself

So the start part would contain:

```
python your_programm.py > $LOGFILE 2>&1 &
ps aux | grep [y]our_programm.py | awk '{print $2}' > $PIDFILE
```

and the stop part:

```
if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
    PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
    kill -9 $PID
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Just missing a '\`' after the `PID=\`cat $PIDFILE`

Answer (score 0):

You can try use supervisor run your program.

[Supervisor: A Process Control System](http://supervisord.org/)